# UITableViewCell - UILabel with attributed text

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a table view with cells that have a single label inside, nothing strange.
I want that this single label contains a text with 2 different colors:

```
let red = NSAttributedString(string: "Red color", 
                         attributes:
                              [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
                                          NSFontAttributeName: normalFont])
let blue = NSAttributedString(string: "Blue color", 
                          attributes: 
                              [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor(),
                                          NSFontAttributeName: boldFont])

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: red)
attributedText.appendAttributedString(blue)

self.labelInformation.attributedText = attributedText
```

**Problem:** text is all blue and I can't understand why.

If I print out `attributedText` I get:

```
Red color
{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x104249d80> font-family: \"Open Sans\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt";
}Blue color{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x10b51d7c0> font-family: \"Open Sans\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt";
}
```

That seems ok!

Issue has to be related to table view since that same code applied on a view works.

Any advice?

**Update**

This code is inside a method of a custom cell view:

```
class CustomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    func setup() {
       // code above
    }

}
```

In controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomIdentifier") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setup()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: When i am writing this code's equivalent code in swift 3.0 its working quite fine.

Comment: same here. does work in playground swift 3.

Comment: Also, is there any code related to `self.labelInformation` after this snippet you posted

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this block of code? `CellForRow`?

Comment: yes, this code is inside of CustomCell's method called on cellForRow

Answer (score -1):

Try Something Like That

```
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
    //: Make a big blue P
        myMutableString.addAttribute(
            NSFontAttributeName,
            value: UIFont(
                name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",
                size: 36.0)!,
            range: NSRange(
                location:0,
                length:1))
        myMutableString.addAttribute(
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: UIColor.blue(),
            range: NSRange(
                location:0,
                length:1))
```

[Visit this link very well explained](https://makeapppie.com/2016/07/05/using-attributed-strings-in-swift-3-0/)

Answer (score -1):

I find the mistake in AppDelegate I have:

```
 UILabel.appearance().textColor = color
```

So the solution is to put this code on cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.labelInformation.text = nil
    self.labelInformation.textColor = nil
}
```